# HttpUrlConnection on Android Wear with connected phone

Tags: httpurlconnection, wear-os

I am trying to access the network with my Android Wear 2.0 App. 
The Problem:

If the smartwatch is connected with the phone then I get an connection timeout. But if the smartwatch isn´t connected with the phone then the connection works fine.

I am using HttpUrlConnection.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in a different post:
[Android Wear 100% packet loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959780/android-wear-100-packet-loss)

The basic idea is that you should not count on having Wi-Fi on the watch. The user may disable Wi-Fi on the watch and then your application will not work on the watch. Instead you should use your companion phone app to connect to the internet. If the phone isn't connected to your watch then use Wi-Fi.

Even if you want your app to run on an LET enabled watch the user may have turned this off or may not have a SIM card installed. At this point the user will most likely still expect your app to work.

So depending on what it is you're working on, if you want your app to work even while connected to the phone, then make a companion app for the phone. If you want your watch app to be a stand-alone app but you still want to be able to access the internet even when the watch is connected to the phone then you're basically saying that you want to drain the user's battery by using Wi-Fi/LTE instead of going via Bluetooth through the phone to access the web.